# Server side call apiController gives 404 with iis7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

This is my code:

```
1 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
2 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/");
3 HttpResponseMessage message = client.GetAsync("api/MyAPI").Result;
4 IEnumerable<string> supplies = 
                 message.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<string>>().Result;
5 return View(supplies);
```

And the error occurs on line 3 Error:404

But When I use Visual Studio 2010 development server, no errors occur.

Comment: It's returning a 404 just based on how you hosted it. Perhaps you put it in a virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: Yes, I put it in a virtual directory,The virtual path is:'/WebAPITest',and the vs project url:'http://localhost/WebAPITest'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have to take care of the cases yourself here.

For development the path to your API is :

```
http://localhost/api/MyAPI
```

And for production on IIS it is:

```
http://localhost/WebAPITest/api/MyAPI
```

The simplest way, which is what we do in fact at my company, is, put the base path into a configuration (Application Settings maybe) and then do this:

```
Settings.BaseUrl = "http://localhost/";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.BaseUrl);
```

When you deploy to IIS change `Settings.BaseUrl` to `http://localhost/WebAPITest/`.

Ideally you could also drop the VS development server and debug on IIS. (This requires VS running with administrator rights)